# Windows Workflow foundation activity + migration to visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I created a custom worflow activity that inherit from CompositeActivity as shown below using VS2008

```
public class CustomWorkflowActivity : System.Workflow.ComponentModel.CompositeActivity
```

I am able to write the below with no problems

```
<GS0:People365WorkflowActivity x:Class="People365.Workflows.Advance_Loan_1WF"
                           x:Name="Advance_Loan_1"
                           xmlns:GS0="clr-namespace:WorkflowEngine.Engine;assembly=WorkflowEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d2bf1cbcd6bbcd82"
                           xmlns:GS1="clr-namespace:WorkflowEngine.ActivityLibrary;assembly=WorkflowEngine.ActivityLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d2bf1cbcd6bbcd82"
                           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<GS1:People365SequenceActivity x:Name="Activity2" WorkflowTemplateActivityId="a6b6327b-c27f-459e-a933-c3cf66ab711f" IsMandatoryActivity="False"></GS1:People365SequenceActivity>
</GS0:People365WorkflowActivity>
```

after migrating the application to VS2010, the below errors appear

- The type 'People365WorkflowActivity' does not support direct content.
- Type 'WorkflowEngine.Engine.People365WorkflowActivity' does not have a suitable TypeConverter or content property to handle this content.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the bellow:

```
<GS0:People365WorkflowActivity x:Class="People365.Workflows.Advance_Loan_1WF"
  x:Name="Advance_Loan_1" xmlns:GS0="clr-    
  namespace:WorkflowEngine.Engine;assembly=WorkflowEngine,Version=1.0.0.0, 
  Culture=neutral, 
  PublicKeyToken=d2bf1cbcd6bbcd82" xmlns:GS1="clr-    
  namespace:WorkflowEngine.ActivityLibrary;assembly=WorkflowEngine.ActivityLibrary, 
  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d2bf1cbcd6bbcd82"     
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <GS0:People365WorkflowActivity.Activities>
      <GS1:People365SequenceActivity x:Name="Activity2" 
          WorkflowTemplateActivityId="a6b6327b-c27f-459e-a933-c3cf66ab711f" IsMandatoryActivity="False">
      </GS1:People365SequenceActivity>
   </GS0:People365WorkflowActivity.Activities>
</GS0:People365WorkflowActivity>
```